# MongoDB Compass - deleting documents permanently

Tags: mongodb

I have a localhost mongodb instance running and can connect to that database via MongoDB Compass

If i want to delete a record I can click on a document and select the Delete button which will flag that document for deletion.

However, I had an issue where when I filtered upping a collection, and deleted all the documents that appear, they come back after i click the refresh button/rerun the filter query

How do I ensure the deletion is permanent?

Comment: While doing `.findAll` do you filter by that flag?

Comment: I think you misunderstood how the delete works: [Compass - Delete Document](https://docs.mongodb.com/compass/current/documents/delete/)

Comment: @AyushGupta I only filter by a simple field. I.e. 

{processId:1005}

Once I filter using above, I delete all the records that show. But once I rerun the same filter, the records I deleted come back

Comment: @prasad_ I'm not sure I understand your comment sorry. I'm using full version of MongoDB Compass (not the read only version). Your link shows how i delete the documents

Comment: @CaptainObv can you show how you "flag that document for deletion."

Comment: @AyushGupta hi yes, if you open the link (and click on table view tab) from prasads comment that is all I am doing. Select deletion and then when the message asking to confirm deletion appears I confirm it

Answer (score 1):

Another option you can use is Compass Embedded Shell and execute `deleteMany` command. This way you won't have to delete individual documents.

I have tested with `deleteMany` and pressed ***REFERESH*** button after execution, and documents were deleted permanently.

Here is an example with `find` command.

[image]